# AngularJS filter on multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table that is populated from $scope and two search textboxes in header that I am using to filter user name and e-mail:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchName"></th>
    <th><input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchMail"> </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>password</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="q in dataForTable | filter:{user_fullname : searchName, user_email : searchMail}">
    <td>{{q.user_id}}</td>
    <td>{{q.user_fullname}}</td>
    <td>{{q.user_email}}</td>
    <td>{{q.user_password}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

dataForTable comes from controller via $http :

```
$http.get('http://tbrzica.comli.com/rest/index.php/simple/users').success(function(data){
   $scope.dataForTable=data;
});
```

But when the page initially load, table is empty. Only when I write something in textboxes and delete the input, table is populated and search by both condition is working normally. Is this some kind of bug?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Found a solution:**

I've needed to initialize two ng-model parameters inside controller:

```
$scope.searchName="";
$scope.searchhMail="";
```

tymeJV, thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sounds like a digest cycle is never being started (`$http` should start one automatically). Is that `$http` call in your controller or a service?

Comment: It is called in controller

Comment: Put a log statement inside the `success`, is the log called on page load?

Comment: I've put console.log('I'm here') inside $http and it executes on page load. You can check it on http://tbrzica.comli.com.

Comment: Found It!! Inside controller I've to initialize two serch parameters:  $scope.searchName=""; $scope.searchMail="";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the controller, you can create a scope function for filter as following:

```
$scope.filterUser = function(fullName, email) {
    return function(user) {
        return (fullName == undefined || fullName.length == 0 || user.user_fullname == fullName)
            && (email == undefined || email.length == 0 || user.user_email == email);
    }
}
```

And in HTML, you can apply the filter following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="q in dataForTable | filter:filterUser(searchName, searchMail)">
    <td>{{q.user_id}}</td>
    <td>{{q.user_fullname}}</td>
    <td>{{q.user_email}}</td>
    <td>{{q.user_password}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this help!